# How to get S3 endpoint using aws region in AWS cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, endpoints

I want to get the endpoint of a given region.
Here is the link of the S3 regions and thier correspondiong endpoint.

Ex.

- for us-east-1, the endpoint is s3.amazonaws.com,
- for us-east-2, the
  endpoint is s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com,
- for us-east-2, the endpoint
  is s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, and so on...

Is there any way to get the endpoints via AWS cli?
Thanks :)

Comment: Add something that you tried, then only we can offer you some help.

Comment: I tried searching any way but I haven't found any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an API for this.

If you like consistency, and a formula that should be valid for all regions going forward, then you might like this format:

```
s3.dualstack.${region}.amazonaws.com
```

All regions support this format, including us-east-1, and this endpoint is dual-stack, so it works with IPv4 and IPv6.

You can also prepend the bucket name and a dot to the beginning and have the individual bucket endpoint.

See the official list at [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried 
aws ec2 describe-regions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html